# Graphics quality in android?

Tags: android, graphics

I'm using Android 2D graphics, doing stuff like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, null);
```

I'd like to know if an option exists to render high quality graphics.

In Swing I would use the `RenderingHints`, but does this concept exist in Android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to use [Paint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#Paint%28int%29) with [anti-aliasing](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG). In the code you used null (last parameter of canvas.drawLine(...) ).

Comment: It **does** look better! Thanks.